# gulp rollup not working external resource import

Tags: javascript, gulp, rollupjs

I'm using gulp-rollup plugin with properly configured babel. Transpiled code from babel needs babel-polyfill to be loaded so I put

```
import "babel-polyfill";
```

at the top of my main file (babel-polyfill is of course installed).

Unfortunatelly, gulp outputted something like this

```
'babel-polyfill' is imported by src/main.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
```

In rollup call, I used

```
allowRealFiles: true
```

So, rollup is able to touch real file system.

Unfortunately, in outputted code, no polyfill code is present.

How to fix it ?

EDIT: I added and configured rollup-plugin-commonjs, not helped

Answer (score 1):

adding rollup-plugin-node-resolve resolved the problem

rollup is not able to touch npm registry by default and needs plugin to do it