# Can not Import React Router Dom In Gulp Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, react-router-dom

This my first experience on gulp. I try to import `react-route-dom` in my `index.jsx`. But when I try to import it, I faced with this error message :

> 'react-router-dom' is imported by projectMyAccount.Site\project.MyAccount.Site.Desktop\scripts\js\desktop\bundle\app.js, but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency
>   No name was provided for external module 'react-router-dom' in options.globals – guessing 'reactRouterDom'

Index Jsx:

```
import Index from '../pages/MyAccount/Index';
import Support  from '../pages/Support/Index';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Pager extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        <Router>
     <div>
         <ul>
             <li><Link to="/test1">Home</Link></li>
             <li><Link to="/about-us">About Use</Link></li>
         </ul>

         <hr/>

         <Route path="/hesabim" component={Index}/>
         <Route path="/about" component={Support}/>
     </div>
 </Router>
    }
};
```

main gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('es6', function () {
  return gulp.src(filePath + '/scripts/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/scripts/js'));
});

gulp.task('react', function () {
    return gulp.src(filePath + '/scripts/jsx/**/*.jsx')
        .pipe(react({harmony: false, es6module: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/scripts/js/'));
});

gulp.task('create-app', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      filePath + '/Scripts/js/desktop/pages/Index.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concatJs("hepsiburada.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/scripts/js/desktop/bundle'))
    .pipe(rollup({
      allowRealFiles: true,
      "format": "iife",
      "plugins": [
        require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
          "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
          "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
        })
      ],
      entry: filePath + '/scripts/js/desktop/bundle/app.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(filePath + '/build/scripts/'));
});
```

What is wrong? Do I have to import another packages for gulp? It is not clear for me. I can use it with unpkg package like this :

```
import Index from '../pages/MyAccount/Index';
import Support  from '../pages/Support/Index';
class Pager extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){

        const Router = ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter;
        const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
        const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;

        return (<Router>
     <div>
         <ul>
             <li><Link to="/test1">Home</Link></li>
             <li><Link to="/about-us">About Use</Link></li>
         </ul>

         <hr/>

         <Route path="/hesabim" component={Index}/>
         <Route path="/about" component={Support}/>
     </div>
 </Router>);
    }

};
```

But I think it is not good for development for a long period. How can I implement it from node modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may need to add rollup-plugin-node-resolve to your gulp.  See possible answer here: [gulp rollup not working external resource import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401386/gulp-rollup-not-working-external-resource-import/42401752#42401752)

Comment: After I do it I get another error  `Error: 'default' is not exported by node_modules\history\createBrowserHistory.js`

Comment: OK! after I add rollup commonjs with it, problem have been fixed. Thank you so much.